# Understanding the proof of inversion formula for density using characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

The formula is:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\lambda x}\hat{f}(\lambda)d\lambda$

where $\hat{f}$ is the characteristic function, $f$ is continuous bounded on 
$R$ and both $f,\hat{f}$ are integrable.

Proof:

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\lambda x}\hat{f}(\lambda)d\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\lambda x}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda y}f(y)dy) d\lambda $

At this point, the proof says we cannot change the order of integration and hence we introduce a regularizing factor $g(\epsilon \lambda)=e^{-\lambda^2\epsilon^2/2}$ by:

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\lambda x}\hat{f}(\lambda)d\lambda = lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\lambda x}\hat{f}(\lambda)g(\epsilon \lambda)d\lambda$

And then he was able to change the order of integration. So I do not understand why we had to introduce $g(\epsilon \lambda)$ because if $f$ is integrable, $e^{i\lambda(y-x)}f(y)$ would be integrable over $R^2$ and can change the order of integration, right? Appreciate a hint, thanks!

Comment: The map $(y,\lambda) \mapsto |e^{i\lambda(y-x)}f(y)|$ is not integrable with respect to the product measure.

Comment: I am not able to understand why that is so? I am thinking of $e^{i\lambda (y-x)}f(y)$ being bound by $f(y)$ and is hence integrable. I am wrong but don't know why? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the function $y \mapsto |f(y)|$ is integrable with respect to $y$ but the function $(y,\lambda) \mapsto |f(y)|$ is not integrable with respect to the product measure (unless $\int |f|$ is zero).